# DNN site - Cannot even SEE the admin login anymore

Tags: dotnetnuke

DNN 6.2.7 - I have a local sandbox installed - there is almost literally nothing there.  It was working fine yesterday; somehow overnight something changed and now when I hit the site the management login of site does not appear any longer.  I am fairly new to DNN and have no idea what has happend.  Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: A littlemore info - I was able to hit the login by explicity entering the URL http://localhost/sitename/login.aspx - now that I was able to log in - now it does not show the control for logging out.  This seems like a problem with the in-built functionality.  but nothing was changed on the site. I do not understand.

Comment: Are you able to navigate to any other pages? What skin are you using on your site?

Comment: Yes I can navigate to other pages.  I am using the WET 3.o GoC skin from github:  CLF3

Comment: If it happened over night and it is local to your machine, chances are some patches were applied of some Internet settings were changed by your Administrators.  I've had this happen several times at my previous job.

Of course, they will DENY any knowledge of ANY changes they have made.